# Saving objects in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been working on this extension and I've come up with a problem. I've tried to use sync and local storage for saving data but always when I close the object disappear. So is there a way to fix my problem or an alternative way to save objects on chrome orI'm stuck with front-end web development.

here is code if you need

```
objekat={
    Opis:opis.value,
    Broj:select.value,
    Tip:tip
}

chrome.storage.sync.set({objekat},function() {
          console.log('Value is set to ' , objekat);
});


chrome.storage.sync.get(objekat,function(result) {
      console.log('Value currently is ', result.Broj);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing `{objekat}` it means `{objekat: objekat}` so you create one key 'objekat' in the storage that contains the entire object, but then you read three keys at once by using `get(object)` syntax so of course there's nothing as you didn't write those individual keys.

Solution:

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get('objekat', result => {
  console.log('Value currently is ', result.objekat.Broj);
});
```

- The API is asynchronous so your `get` may be easily running before `set` completes. To prevent that, put the entire `get` block inside the callback of `set`.
- You can save all keys as separate entries in the storage and read them all at once or individually:

  ```js
  chrome.storage.sync.set(objekat, () => {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('Broj', result => {
      console.log('Broj:', result.Broj);
    });
    chrome.storage.sync.get(objekat, result => {
      console.log('All values', result);
    });
  });
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but my storage is not being saved after I quit. Do you have another solution? But thanks it means a lot to me.

Comment: @Matija, there's no "other" solution as this is the only one. There's probably a mistake in the other part of your code which I can't guess from the code you posted in your question. You should either provide a more complete and realistic [MCVE](/help/mcve) or the question will be closed.

Answer (score -1):

There is a different approach to save data into localStorage and I didn't notice it

```
//                    Key   save whole object
localStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(objekat))
```

and to get data out of localStorage use thru the function

```
function getdata(){
    var val = localStorage.getItem(objekat.ID);
    return val;
}
```